# -viewDidUnload is not called after memory warning when xib is not used

Tags: iphone, ios

When I use xib, -viewDidUnload is called after memory warning.
But when I create view programmatically instead of using xib, -viewDidUnload is not called.

(In both cases, -didReceiveMemoryWarning is called.)

Why -viewDidUnload is not called when I don't use xib file?
Don't I have to write code for -viewDidUnload if I don't use xib?

The followings are the test code and results: 
(I'm using ARC)

```
@implementation ViewControllerA
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", gNavigationController.viewControllers.count];

    // button to pop view controller to navigation controller
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 50);
    [button setTitle:@"push" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(push) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    // button to generate memory warning
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 50);
    [button setTitle:@"memory warning" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(generateMemoryWarning) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    NSLog(@"view did load %@", self.title);
}

- (void)generateMemoryWarning {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)];
}

- (void)push {
    UIViewController *viewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc] init];
    [gNavigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    NSLog(@"view did unload %@", self.title);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    NSLog(@"view did receive memory warning %@", self.title);
}

@end
```

**RESULTS**

**if ViewControllerA doesn't have xib:**

```
view did load 1
view did load 2
view did receive memory warning 1
view did receive memory warning 2
```

**if ViewControllerA has xib:**

```
view did load 1
view did load 2
view did unload 1
view did receive memory warning 1
view did receive memory warning 2
```

Comment: Do you create your view and set it (self.view = myView;) in loadView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `UIViewContoller` without initializing it from a NIB, you need to subclass the `-loadView` method. Otherwise iOS assumes that the view cannot be unloaded / reloaded.

It would be sufficient to just add the following to your implementation:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.view = yourCreatedView;
}
```

Unfortunately the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) is not very clear on this.

Comment: Thanks for very helpful answer! -viewDidUnload was called when I added the -loadView. 
But if I don't want iOS to unload my view, not setting self.view is good? Or should I always set my created view to self.view?

Comment: if you dont want iOS to unload your View, you should not be setting self.view, but optimum use(MVC) should be creating a UIView and assigning it to self.view

Comment: Minor nitpick (sorry), the apple documentation for loadview specifies "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super." per http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html